# Access image in table using Watin

Tags: c#, watin

I'm trying to click a clickable image using Watin, but I'm having a hard time getting to its level inside a table.

Here is the web code:

```
<td class="KPagerCell">
<a class="PagerHyperlinkStyle" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvBills$viewPager','2')" title=" Next to Page 2">
    <img src="../Resources/Images/next.gif" alt="next">
</a>
```

Here's my C#:

```
TableRow trpage = tb.TableRow(Find.ByClass("GridPager"));
TableCell tdPage = trpage.TableCell(Find.ById("ctl00_Main_lvBills_colPager"));
Table page = tdPage.Table(Find.ByClass("KPager"));
//TableBody tbpage = page.TableCell(Find.ByClass("KPagerInfoCell")).Parent.Parent as TableBody;
TableRow trkeypager = page.TableRow(Find.ByClass("KPager"));
TableCell tdkeypager = trkeypager.TableCell(Find.ByClass("KPagerCell"));
Link nxtpage = tdkeypager.Image(Find.ByAlt("next")).Parent as Link;
Image nxt = nxtpage.Image(Find.ByAlt("next"));
nxt.Click();
```

And the error:

```
Could not find IMG or INPUT (image) element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'alt' equals 'next' at https://secure6.i-doxs.net/WaterOne/Secure/Bills.aspx
```

These pages are behind a login, so you won't be able to see it in practice. Hopefully I've given enough context.

Comment: Shouldn't you be clicking the anchor, not the img? (Though Watin is pretty versatile, so the latter probably still works.) Also, (out of curiosity) which `Image` call fails--the first or the second?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to click on the link, but it failed on the link one, because it is not able to find the image which we put as the child to find the link as its parent.

Comment: I cannot access the page you are referring to, but testing against the main page with the "Enroll" button (a similar link/image combo), Watin seems handle clicking the image just fine. Are you certain that the objects you are locating prior to the `Image` code are finding the correct elements of the page? Have you tried inspecting the `OuterHtml` of some of those elements to confirm they are the correct elements being sought?

Comment: I cannot understand why you need the image to find the link use the class on the link to click on it. something like this tdkeypager.Link(Find.ByClass("PagerHyperlinkStyle")).Click(); this will trigger the JS.